# How to print a list of threads with Java 8 stream api

Tags: java, algorithm, collections, java-8

I tried something like

```
  Thread
        .getAllStackTraces()
        .keySet()
        .stream()
        .map(
                $->{
                    System.out.println
                    ($.getStackTrace());
                    return $;
                    });
```

I feel like thats not the best way to do it. Is there other way?
*What is the shortest way to do it?* Using the **Stream API**. (need to print the whole stack traces)

Comment: `forEach`?.....

Comment: You're doing extra work if you want to get each stack trace.  Before anyone broaches a solution, is that what you're after?  (By the way, they're not lists, they're `StackTraceElement[]`, and they can be *expensive* to generate.)

Comment: can you write a code that is getting the real stack?

Answer (score 7):

Are you aware, that [`Thread.getAllStackTraces()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getAllStackTraces--) returns a `Map` that already contains all stack traces? Iterating over the `Thread` keyset, to call `Thread.getStackTrace()` for each of them, is not only a waste of resources, it also raises the chances of getting less useful results, as threads may terminate while you are iterating, resulting in empty stack traces, whereas the `Map` contains a snapshot made at the point of time when you invoked `getAllStackTraces()`.

You can simply iterate over the values instead:

```
Thread.getAllStackTraces().values().stream()
      .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

While this fulfills the requirement of just printing all stack traces, this unformatted output is unlikely to be useful.

You may prefer:

```
Thread.getAllStackTraces().forEach((t,st) -> {
    System.out.printf("Thread %4d %-20s %13s pri=%d%n",
                      t.getId(), t.getName(), t.getState(), t.getPriority());
    Arrays.stream(st).forEachOrdered(ste -> System.out.println("\tat "+ste));
});
```

Answer (score 4):

how about: `Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet().stream().map(Thread::getStackTrace).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println)`?

---

EDIT: The above code requires some editing to get to look nice. Here is a version with nicer formatting:

```
Thread.getAllStackTraces()
      .keySet()
      .stream()
      .map(Thread::getStackTrace)
      .map(Arrays::asList)
      .forEach(list -> System.out.println(list.stream()
                                              .map(i -> i.toString())
                                              .collect(Collectors.joining("\n\t"))))
```

Comment: [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@4c873330
[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@119d7047
[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@776ec8df
[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@4eec7777
[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@3b07d329 thats it what it prints!!!! NOT THE RIGHT ANSWER

Comment: It should print the same thing you mentioned before. if you would like it to print something else, simply change the ```System.out::println``` to a function of your choice

Comment: need the whole stacktraces

Comment: Please see my updated answer to print the list of arrays

Comment: Yeps its almost perfect. Printing the stacktraces on one line :(

Comment: People do you mind if I leave the question for a weak and make a bounty on it +100. I want to see the best styles of code, we can leart a lot from that thing.

Comment: Feel free. Please bear in mind that if you would like specific formatting, you must be more specific (I.E. a single element on each line with hanging indent and double space between traces)

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED** (thx @Flown)

Try this:

```
 Thread
        .getAllStackTraces()
        .keySet()
        .forEach($ -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString($.getStackTrace()));
```

Comment: hmm shall it print?

Comment: One can't simply print an array and expect the output to be intelligible...

Comment: Well wrap the sysout into `Arrays.toString($.getStackTrace())`

Comment: works perfect I gave thumbs up, you were -1, but you are still skipping the topic- streams collections